# Mac OS X, how to add a Domain user to a Local Group?

Tags: mac, domain, user, local

Trying to add Active Directory domain users to a local group in Mac OS X. The Mac is bound to the domain. The group of users is not a group on the domain, so I created a local group, but need to add users from the domain to that group.

I can accomplish this using the Mac OS Server app, but: Big Sur is experiencing network issues on older Mac hardware (drops off network), Apple doesn't have older server apps available for download, and the only Server app available won't work on anything older than Big Sur. All of this is moot if I can add domain users to a local group.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with either `dslc` or `dseditgroup`. Here's an example using `dscl`

`sudo dscl . -append /Groups/admin GroupMembership some_user`

`.` specifies the local groups. The rest should be self-explanatory. You can look at the man page for details.

Here's a `dseditgroup` example from it's man page.

> `dseditgroup −o edit −n /LDAPv3/ldap.company.com −u myusername −p −a username −t user extragroup`
>
> The group extragroup from the node /LDAPv3/ldap.company.com will have
> the username added if the username is in a user record on the search
> policy and if the correct password is presented interactively for the
> user myusername which also need to have write access.